# Xcode fails to recognize dispatch_once block as correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I'm using this common code style in multiple different places throughout my codebase, however in one location, Xcode all of a sudden doesn't like it:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    ...
});
```

It shows the following error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types passing 'void *(^)(void)' to parameter of type 'dispatch_block_t _Nonnull' (aka 'void (^)(void)')
```

The style is exactly the same as in other parts of the code, so I'm kind of at a loss as to what exactly is the issue here.

It also has the following error at the closing brace of the block:

```
Control may reach end of non-void block
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss any bracket or have an unwanted return statement, it is difficult to tell with what you have posted.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yea there was an unwanted return statement. It just wasn't clear to me what the issue was. This is only week two for me with Objective-C :)

Answer (score -1):

Upon further inspection, there was an instance in the block where I had `return nil;` (I had added the dispatch code retroactively)

Because of that return statement XCode assumed the block had a `void *` return type which didn't match the expected block signature for `dispatch_once`, hence the error at the beginning of the block instead of where the problem was.